# Finding common values for a given key in dict where each value is a set

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I have two dicts created from csv files (see file below):

```
a_data = {
    '78567908': {'26.01.21', '02.03.24', '26.01.12', '02.03.01', '04.03.03', '01.01.13', '01.01.10', '26.01.17'},
    '85789070': {'02.03.17', '02.05.01', '02.05.04', '26.01.02', '09.01.04'},
    '87140110': {'03.15.19', '03.15.25', '03.15.24'},
    '87142218': {'26.17.13', '02.03.22', '02.11.01'},
    '87006826': {'28.01.03'}
}

p_data = {
    '78567908': {'24.11.01', '26.01.21', '24.11.02', '02.03.24', '02.03.01', '04.03.03', '01.01.13', '26.01.18', '01.01.10'},
    '85789070': {'02.05.05', '02.03.17', '02.05.24', '02.05.01', '02.05.04', '26.01.02', '09.01.04'},
    '87140110': {'03.15.19', '03.15.25', '03.15.10', '03.15.24'},
    '87142218': {'26.17.13', '02.03.22', '02.11.01', '02.03.02', '02.03.24', '02.11.13'},
    '87006826': {'28.01.03'}
}
```

I am trying to compare `p_data` to `a_data`. **I want to know for each key  in `a_data` & `p_data`, what is the intersection & what values are in `a_data` but not in `p_data`.**

for key `78567908`, `p_data` has 6 out of 8 values. The common values are

```
01.01.10
01.01.13
02.03.01
02.03.24
04.03.03
26.01.21
```

and the missing values are

```
26.01.12
26.01.17
```

The csv files look like this:

```
78567908,01.01.10,01.01.13,02.03.01,02.03.24,04.03.03,26.01.12,26.01.17,26.01.21
85789070,02.03.17,02.05.01,02.05.04,09.01.04,26.01.02
87140110,03.15.19,03.15.24,03.15.25
87142218,02.03.22,02.11.01,26.17.13
87006826,28.01.03
```

I created the dicts using this code:

```
a_data = {}
with open(cvsfile) as fin:
    reader = csv.reader(fin, skipinitialspace=True)
    for row in reader:
        a_data[row[0]]=set(row[1:])
```

If there is a better way than dicts (like data frames) to arrive as the same product, I will accept that as an answer. So far, I've only managed to create two dictionaries or data frames, but no progress on comparing the two dicts/data frames.

Comment: Please format blocks of code by indenting each line four spaces or using the `{}` toolbar button. Backticks don't work well for multiline blocks

Comment: The code and input file you show have nothing to do with the question you are asking. Could you please show your attempt at solving the problem at hand?

Comment: @MadPhysicist, thank you for editing the post for formatting.

Comment: You're welcome. Now could you please add the *relevant* code I requested? It would also be nice to know what kind of output you had in mind.

Comment: To try and help out here with what you want... does something like: `{k: (v & p_data[k], v - p_data[k]) for k, v in a_data.items() if k in p_data}` get close to your desired output... so you get the key value that's in a and also in p, and a 2-tuple of the intersection and difference of values as the values?

Comment: @JonClements I think that would work if i understand correctly. For each key in a_data also in p_data, I would get a 2-tuple ([values in a_data and p_data], [values in a_data and not in p_data]).

Comment: Yes... if you copy/paste your dicts into an interpreter and run the line above, you'll see the results if are actually what you're after (and hopefully they're or they're close enough to adjust accordingly)

Comment: @MadPhysicist I don't have any relevant code. I've read in the csv files, created dicts where the key is the 0 element of a line and the values are a set of the remaining elements. I'm able to iterate over all of the values in the set of each key. But i don't have anything that I think is relevant to answering my question.

Comment: @JonClements - Results look correct. Thank you

Comment: Well, if someone wants to make an answer to that affect - that'd be great then :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
a_data = {'78567908': {'26.01.21', '02.03.24', '26.01.12', '02.03.01', '04.03.03', '01.01.13', '01.01.10', '26.01.17'}, '85789070': {'02.03.17', '02.05.01', '02.05.04', '26.01.02', '09.01.04'}, '87140110': {'03.15.19', '03.15.25', '03.15.24'}, '87142218': {'26.17.13', '02.03.22', '02.11.01'}, '87006826': {'28.01.03'}}

p_data = {'78567908': {'24.11.01', '26.01.21', '24.11.02', '02.03.24', '02.03.01', '04.03.03', '01.01.13', '26.01.18', '01.01.10'}, '85789070': {'02.05.05', '02.03.17', '02.05.24', '02.05.01', '02.05.04', '26.01.02', '09.01.04'}, '87140110': {'03.15.19', '03.15.25', '03.15.10', '03.15.24'}, '87142218': {'26.17.13', '02.03.22', '02.11.01', '02.03.02', '02.03.24', '02.11.13'}, '87006826': {'28.01.03'}}

a = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(a_data, orient='index')
p = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(p_data, orient='index')

a.apply(lambda x: sum(i in p.loc[x.name,:].tolist() for i in x.dropna()), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
78567908    6
85789070    5
87140110    3
87142218    3
87006826    1
dtype: int64
```